# Generic sorting for all types of STL containers

Tags: c++

I am learning C++ **iterator_traits** using which I am implementing generic sorting for all C++ STL containers (std::vector, std::forward_list etc.). But I'm facing some problems in getting this functionality done. This is my sample code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<forward_list>
#include<iterator>


template<typename For>
void sortHelper(For beg, For end, std::forward_iterator_tag)
{
    std::vector<decltype(*beg)> Temp {beg, end};
    std::sort(Temp.begin(), Temp.end());
    std::copy(Temp.begin(), Temp.end(), beg);
}


template<typename Ran>
void sortHelper(Ran beg, Ran end, std::random_access_iterator_tag)
{
    std::sort(beg, end);
}


template<typename Container>
void sortData(Container& cont)
{
    sortHelper(cont.begin(), cont.end(), typename std::iterator_traits<typename Container::iterator>::iterator_category);
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> VectorList {223, 234, 45, 6456, 556, 34324, 678, 1231};
    std::forward_list<int> ForwardList {234234, 345345, 31, 456, 454, 34, 3242, 96};

    std::cout << "Before sorting VectorList:" << std::endl;
    for(auto x : VectorList)
        std::cout << x <<"\t";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Before sorting ForwardList:" << std::endl;
    for(auto x : ForwardList)
        std::cout << x <<"\t";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    sortData(VectorList);
    sortData(ForwardList);

    std::cout << "After sorting VectorList:" << std::endl;
    for(auto x : VectorList)
        std::cout << x <<"\t";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "After sorting ForwardList:" << std::endl;
    for(auto x : ForwardList)
        std::cout << x <<"\t";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting the below compiler error

```
Test2.cpp:25:117: error: expected ‘(’ before ‘)’ token
  sortHelper(cont.begin(), cont.end(), typename std::iterator_traits<typename Container::iterator>::iterator_category);
```

Comment: `iterator_category` is a type. Since you want an object of that type, you need to initialize it somehow. Adding `()` or `{}` should do it. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: @StoryTeller I tried that but still getting compiler error

Comment: Yes, but not *that* error. You have  a few mistakes in that code. A missing include for `<algorithm>` and `decltype(*beg)` deducing a reference. Neither is related to the problem you asked about.

Comment: @StoryTeller Well I just copied that code from Bjarne Stroustrup's C++ book. Anyhow I got it corrected by replacing decltype(*beg) with typename For::value_type